# Add grub to windows boot manager

Tags: windows, grub

I have a Windows , Linux and Android installed. So grub is very important. I added it by installing on a partition than using dd to copy it as mbr and add it as boot selector. But the process is hard. And grub2win gives a download timeout at installation.I often get mbr file broken and it's frustrating to install it.

Is there a way to automate or easily install grub and add it to boot loader like using ubndlr?

How does unetbootin work?

Answer (score 3):

You most likely have a machine that supports UEFI. You'll have to use the EFI System Partition to install the grub.efi bootloader.

EDIT: You can see all of your currently installed UEFI bootloaders in windows, using `bcdedit.exe /enum {fwbootmgr}` if you use powershell, put `"{fwbootmgr}"` in quotes `"`.

NOTES:

1.) `{bootmgr}` is for entries in the Windows Boot Manager. `{fwbootmgr}` is for entries in the UEFI boot list.

2.) You'l need to mount the hard drive in a linux distro in order to see/edit the ESP(EFI System Partition).

Comment: Actually, you can place several EFI files in the ESP(EFI System Partition), each in its own folder. Your BIOS will pick each one up, and youll need to select it in your BIOS screen.

Comment: So, you'll want to go into your BIOS and select to boot the grub.efi bootloader. Naturally, it wont be so well worded, it will probably be a confusing mess of UEFI bootloaders, without their names.

Comment: Your not using the windows bootloader at all, you are using your UEFI BIOS to start the grub bootloader, which can then start the windows bootloader.

Comment: I found a way to make portable mbr